# "One sided" fast times of Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$, $t \in [0,1]$ be a standard Brownian motion.  We call a time $t$ *fast up* if
$$
\limsup_{h \searrow 0} \frac{B(t+h) - B(t)}{\sqrt{2 h \ln(1/h)}} =1.
$$
(Note the absence of absolute value here.) Likewise call a *time fast* down if the $\liminf$ is $-1$.

Question: Are there times that are fast up but **not** fast down?  (I think yes, but got stuck in the proof.  Perhaps naively, I guess all fast times are either up or down.)

---

This is vaguely related to 
[Can a Brownian motion be fast at its extrema?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195179/can-a-brownian-motion-be-fast-at-its-extrema)
(which itself was motivated by [Location of maximum of Brownian motion with rough drift](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193848/location-of-maximum-of-brownian-motion-with-rough-drift).  The relevance to the original question is that I suspect the set of fast down only times contains the argmax of the sum, with positive probability, so there is no density.)